# Creating Sum/Total rows by user in sql query for csv/excel report

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

The query below pulls in data to form a 'report' but it's basically just line items of numbers grouped by 
CSR agent. What it does is accurate and correct, and after the query I save the results as a CSV. However,
it's only giving me the individual records, so I have to put it into excel and use formulas to insert a
'Totals' row that basically sums up the columns I need to be totalled.

This sql query runs in a php script, but I'm not sure the best way to go about modifying any of this so that 
I can total those columns for each user. It would somehow have to say 'This is the end of records for user 7200
so insert row of totals for user 7200 and then move on to records for user 7206' or something to that effect.

The screenshot shows the report as it is, using "x's" and null spaces instead of 1 or 0, so in my excel formulas
I usuall have a count IF "x" variable. I'm hoping I can do something similar with this script. The query and 
screenshot are below.

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6a568/1

The output of the fiddle is the output of the exact query, the only difference is the script puts it into csv.

I'm just hoping there's a way to create a 'Totals' row for each user that will add up the number of "x's" and 
the amount of seconds for duration and hold time.

Any suggestions to how I can refactor this are greatly appreciated.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn2,
    "SELECT
          FirstN
          , LastN
        , Extension
        , Recieved
        , Recieved_Known
        , Outbound
        , Outbound_Known
        , Missed_No_VM
        , Missed_VM
        , Missed_Known
        , Calling_Number
        , Called_Number
        , Start_Time
        , End_Time
        , Talk_Time_Seconds
        , Hold_Time_Seconds

        FROM (
          SELECT distinct
           firstn
           , lastn
           , c.extension
           , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Recieved
           , case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Recieved_Known
           , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 then 'x' ELSE '' end  AS Outbound
           , case when  FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = kn.long_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Outbound_Known
           , case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 0 and finallycalledpartyno  not like '%oice%' then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_No_VM
           , case when finallycalledpartyno like '%oice%' then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_VM
           , case when legtype1 = 2 and ANSWERED = 0 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as
            Missed_Known
           , a.CALLINGPARTYNO AS Calling_Number
           , a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO AS Called_Number
           , b.starttime as Start_Time
           , b.endtime as End_Time
           , b.duration as Talk_Time_Seconds
           , a.holdtimesecs as Hold_Time_Seconds

          FROM ambition.session a
            INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
            right join jackson_id.users c on a.callingpartyno = c.extension or a.finallycalledpartyno = c.extension
            LEFT JOIN ambition.known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
        left join ambition.known_numbers kn on a.finallycalledpartyno = kn.long_number
                WHERE a.ts >= '2017-12-07' -- curdate()
                and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users) OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from ambition.ambition_users))
          ) x
          order by extension;") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));
```

Screenshot for good measure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how do you uniquely identify the user. I am assuming that the extension is unique for each user. Based on that I come up with the following query:

```
SELECT
          Extension
        , Recieved
        , Recieved_Known
        , Outbound
        , Outbound_Known
        , Missed_No_VM
        , Missed_VM
        , Missed_Known
        , Talk_Time_Seconds
        , Hold_Time_Seconds

      FROM (
          SELECT distinct
           c.extension
           , sum(CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Recieved
           , sum(case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Recieved_Known
           , sum(CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 end)  AS Outbound
           , sum(case when  FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = kn.long_number then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Outbound_Known
           , sum(case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 0 and finallycalledpartyno  not like '%oice%' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Missed_No_VM
           , sum(case when finallycalledpartyno like '%oice%' then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Missed_VM
           , sum(case when legtype1 = 2 and ANSWERED = 0 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 1 ELSE 0 end) as
            Missed_Known
           , sum(b.duration) as Talk_Time_Seconds
           , sum(a.holdtimesecs) as Hold_Time_Seconds

          FROM session a
        INNER JOIN callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
        right join users c on a.callingpartyno = c.extension or a.finallycalledpartyno = c.extension
        LEFT JOIN known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
        left join known_numbers kn on a.finallycalledpartyno = kn.long_number
          WHERE a.ts >= '2017-12-07' -- curdate()
          and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from ambition_users) OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from ambition_users))
        group by c.extension    
      ) x

          order by extension;
```

The above query, at least, will give you some idea on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok so I can see that this will give me the totals separately. Do you know if there's a way for me to insert these though, along with the single records? For instance, have the single records for the user, then this row? Or if nothing else I might could insert both into a single CSV somehow

Comment: After thinking about this more, I would hope I could use a foreach loop around the single records, and insert the totals based on user ID. I'm just sort of reaching here but I'll have to play with it some more probably.

Comment: I dont think I get your requirements properly. But I dont know any way to do this using single query.

Comment: Right, I don't think there would be a way. I'm afraid I'll have to use a loop and try to assign variables to the sql fields